# How to invoke a lambda after create/update in terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm creating/updating a lambda function using terraform and I need to run it AFTER it is created or updated. I know there is a terraform data source `aws_lambda_invocation` but it runs BEFORE the lambda function created/updated.
Is there any way to achieve this in terraform?

Comment: Did you try adding `depends_on` to `aws_lambda_invocation`?

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: Thanks @Marcin. Yes `depends_on` initially didn't work which was because of another problem that I already fixed. So the trick was `depends_on`.

Comment: No problem. I added an answer with example.

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear what you can do?

Answer (score 3):

Normally you would use [depends_on](https://www.terraform.io/language/meta-arguments/depends_on) for that:

```
data "aws_lambda_invocation" "fun" {

  # ...

  depends_on = [aws_lambda_function.fun]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Store your terraform state file in S3. Set trigger on state files update action. So whenever there is a change in terraform it will update statte file in S3. You can set trigger from S3 to trigger lambda.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example.html